# Find a directory that begins with x (Groovy)

Tags: groovy

Using groovy, I want to find a directory that begins with XXXX characters. I'm a groovy newbie and would appreciate any help.

Given directory Y and only searching within Y I need to find a directory that starts with XXXX. It should only be one directory that matches the pattern.

This is for use in Jenkins.

I have tried the following:

```
def release_dir_path = "C:\\Dir\\ReleaseDir"
def pattern = "DWH-4072"
def release_path = ""

new File(release_dir_path).eachDir { File dir -> if 
    (dir.name.startsWith(pattern) { release_path = dir })}
println release_path
```

The idea is to find the directory in Y that starts with XXXX and place that value into release_path.

Comment: where do you want to search, e.g. just in the current directory, or recursively search all subdirs?

Comment: Misplaced ).. problem solved with the following:

    def release_dir_path = 
"C:\\Users\\Peret\\OneDrive\\StarsGroovySandbox\\ReleaseDir"
    def pattern = "DWH-4072"
    def release_path = ""

    new File(release_dir_path).eachDir { File dir -> if 
(dir.name.startsWith(pattern)) { release_path = dir }}
    println release_path

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified:

1. In which directory the search should start
2. How to search i.e. recursively or non-recursively

I'll assume you want to search non-recursively in `/tmp`.

```
// stores each matching directory as a File object
List<File> matchingDirs = []

new File('/tmp').eachDir { File dir ->    
   if (dir.name.startsWith('XXXX')) {
       matchingDirs << dir
   }
}

// after updating your question to explain that there should be just 
// one matching dir and you want to capture it in a variable and print it
if (matchingDirs) {
  def matchingDir = matchingDirs[0]
  println matchingDir
}
```

If you want to search recursively instead, just replace `eachDir` with `eachDirRecurse`.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising.. I'm starting from directory Y and only need to find a subdirectory of Y starting with XXXX, which should be only a single directory.

Comment: With the correction of a misplaced ), I've got it now thank you.

    def release_dir_path = 
    "C:\\Users\\Peret\\OneDrive\\StarsGroovySandbox\\ReleaseDir"
    def pattern = "DWH-4072"
    def release_path = ""

    new File(release_dir_path).eachDir { File dir -> if (dir.name.startsWith(pattern)) { 
    release_path = dir }}
    println release_path

Comment: @PeretzRickett I can't see any substantial difference between your solution and the one I originally proposed, but I've updated my answer to more closely match your updated question